# Android HttpClient' second request Returns "The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response"

Tags: android, httpclient

I use DefaultHttpClient. When i make a request, sometimes entity returns with null and this is ok, but before client's timeout if i make second request i get ***"org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response"*** exception. After timeout, when i make a request, everything works fine.
because of the entity return null i can not call consumeContent() method. Is this a problem? If so what should i do to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the server correctly handle requests and sends a response body?

Comment: As i said server does not send any response body, it just sends me a status code in the header. Should the server always send a response body, is it a must?

Comment: Server does not  should always send a response body. 
If you have access to the server, server logs would be the place to look.

Comment: Then if the entity returns null i can not call consumeContent() method to release the resources so what should i call to release the resources?